# How to add nofollow to frontpage only? (Woocommerce products, internal links)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, nofollow

Currently it add nofollow at all products across website, how to make it at is_front_page() only?..

```
function woocommerce_template_loop_product_title() {
echo '<p class="name product-title ' . esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_loop_title_classes', 'woocommerce-loop-product__title' ) ) . '"><a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '" rel="nofollow">' . get_the_title() . '</a></p>'; // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Change the value of your `rel` attribute. So, when the user is at the `frontpage`, `rel` will have a value of `nofollow`. Otherwise, the value will be `""` empty.

```
<?php

function woocommerce_template_loop_product_title() {

// Add the $nofollow
$nofollow = "";
if(is_front_page() ){
    $nofollow = "nofollow"; 
}

echo '<p class="name product-title ' . esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_loop_title_classes', 'woocommerce-loop-product__title' ) ) . '"><a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '" rel='.$nofollow.'>' . get_the_title() . '</a></p>';
?>
```